# Changing partitions on a Centos 7 system from the command line

Tags: linux, centos

I have just done a fresh install of a Centos 7 system that has 3 disks in it. I have ended up with the following:

```
[root@nas /]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a491f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200  3907028991  1952464896   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00031210

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907028991  1953513472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000839dc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907028991  1953513472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos_nas-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos_nas-swap: 4026 MB, 4026531840 bytes, 7864320 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos_nas-home: 5942.4 GB, 5942389243904 bytes, 11606228992 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

and an fstab of:

```
[root@nas /]# cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Mon Dec  3 19:45:04 2018
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/centos_nas-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=f62f73ae-52eb-49b8-9d40-2cc274c89112 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos_nas-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos_nas-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

Ultimately I want the first disk to be the "system disk" with mount points for / etc.

I then want the second (/dev/sdb) and third disks (/dev/sdc) to be mount points of

```
/disk-2
/disk-3
```

so that I have 3 discrete disks with their own file systems.

As I don't understand how I "undo" the LVM without breaking everything I was hoping someone would be kind enough to let me have the commands to invoke to get my requested partitioning scheme?

Comment: If it's a fresh install reinstalling it with the intended partitioning scheme will be the fastest and most easy option.

Comment: I realise that. Unfortunately I don't have access to the machine again for a week so was hoping to do this remotely.

Comment: What is the result of command `pvs`? Do you want to have those disks in `LVM` or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to ask for the method you probably should not attempt this IMHO.

The recipe (obviously not tested and only for rough guidance rather than copying verbatim) is roughly:

- start by making a backup of your data and verify / test your restore capability

A lot depends on how the physical disks are currently assigned to LVM volume groups, how much space is either free or allocated to LVM logical volumes and how large your file-systems are and how much data is in them. (`pvdisplay` `vgdisplay` `lvdisplay`)

If the installer left much of the available disk space unassigned you can do quite a bit by getting LVM to migrate your data, but if not, you have the added difficulty that AFAIK XFS filesystems can only grow, not shrink and you will to manually back up data and delete LVM partitions to create empty space.

- You need to be able to have/create enough "free" space that /dev/sda2 can be removed from LVM. Then:
- ask LVM kindly to remove all data from the underlying `/dev/sda2` physical disk with **`pvmove /dev/sda2`**
- remove  `/dev/sda2` from LVM with **`vgreduce centos_nas /dev/sda2`** and **`pvremove /dev/sda2`**
- For correctness: change the partition label on sda such that /dev/sda2 becomes "Linux" rather than "Linux LVM" with `fdisk /dev/sda`
- Create a new file system  `mkfs.xfs /dev/sda2`
- Mount the new file system `mkdir /mnt/temp` and `mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/temp`
- Copy the data from the current root file system to the new root file system: `tar --one-file-system -lcf - .|(cd /mnt/temp; tar -xpvf - )` or similar with your choice of backup tool
- change the grub config in `/boot` and the new fstab `/mnt/temp/etc/fstab` to use `/dev/sda2` as the root file system

reboot

hope for the best

After moving the root file system you can move the data from other LVM volumes at your leisure